# Roblox global variable

Tags: global-variables, roblox

In Roblox, I am making where when the player steps on the floor the point value
increases.
This is the script for the floor:

```
    points = -1
    local debounce = false
    local floor = script.Parent
    part.Touched:Connect(function()
        if not debounce then
            debounce = true
            floor.Material = Enum.Material.DiamondPlate
            floor.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Baby blue")
            print("Color and material changed")
            points = points + 1
            print(points)
            label.Text = "Counter: " .. points -- <--The label is underlined  for being undefined
            wait(5)
            floor.Material = Enum.Material.Rock
            floor.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(162, 163, 165)
            print("Color and material reset to normal")
            debounce = false
        end
    end)
```

This is the script for the label:

```
    label = script.Parent
```

The label is underlined because it says Unknown Global 'label'. How is it not  global?

Comment: Heyo, please don't post pictures of your code. Please edit your question and include your code in text form. That way it is easier for us to work with it.

Comment: Ok sorry for that

Comment: You could send events and update the text of label from the event, in a script of the label itself

Comment: Could you please describe your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a global variable, you need to add this.

```
_G label = script.Parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `label = script.Parent` is **above** the code that uses the variable and in the same script.